# Android Request Permission System Overlay Detected

Tags: android, overlay, android-permissions, application-settings, runtime-permissions

I am facing a problem. Which doesn't occur when user has successfully given all the required permissions. It occurs when user had denied to permission. I show user a dialog to enable the permissions from **Apps->AppName->Settings**. I take the user there. But when user try to enable the any of the permissions, it shows the message. **System Overlay Detected** and doesn't allow user to enable any permissions. I searched google and Stackoverflow a lot but didn't find any solution. Some people solved the solution by disabling the toast, but I am not showing any toast.

Note: This problem only occurs when denied for any of the permission.

Here is my code

```
private void showPermissionDialog(String message, final int permissionCode){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Permission Required");

    if(permissionCode == Constants.REQ_CODE_PERMISSION_SYSTEM_OVERLAY_WINDOW) {
        builder.setMessage(Constants.getOverlayNotEnabledMessage(Constants.getInstance(this)));
    } else {
        builder.setMessage(message + " To enable go to apps, Select " +
                getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + " Enable permissions now?");
    }

    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
            if(permissionCode == Constants.REQ_CODE_PERMISSION_READ_CONTACTS){
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            if(permissionCode == Constants.REQ_CODE_PERMISSION_SYSTEM_OVERLAY_WINDOW) {
                requestOverlayPermissions();
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), null);
                intent.setData(uri);
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(intent, permissionCode);
            }
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In android M, there is no solution to this problem. If your application require `SYSTEM_OVERLAY_WINDOW` permission you cannot enable or disable permissions from Settings. The only solution (No solution at developer side) is clear app data, this will again request permissions